# delete distinct data mysql and laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mysqli

hi i have laravel project 
and i have this model

```
User_attendance

User
```

and i have this relation inside `User`

```
public function getAttendance()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User_attendance','user_attendance_user_id','id');
}
```

now there is duplication data in User_attendance like this

```
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48
9238<><> 2018-11-28 17:35:00
9238<><> 2018-11-29 17:44:34
9238<><> 2018-12-08 17:18:12
9238<><> 2018-12-08 17:18:12
```

now `9238<><> 2018-11-27 17:45:48`
 has 12 recored 
how can i run query inside laravel or mysql to delete 11 recored and leave only 1 
i did this

```
$users = User::limit(30)->get();
foreach($users as $u)
{
    foreach($u->getAttendance as $attendance)
    {
        echo $attendance->user_attendance_user_id . "<><> ".$attendance->created_at ."<br />";
    }
}
```

i want to delete the duplication data and leave only one recored 
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the DISTINCT or GROUP BY keyword

Example:

SELECT DISTINCT(column),column1,column2,... FROM table_name;

SELECT * From User_attendance GROUP BY user_attendance_user_id,created_at;

Answer (score 1):

Use a double group by something like :

```
DB::table('users')
            ->select('*')
            ->groupBy('user_attendance_user_id','created_at')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete records in the databse, you could do a MySQL query like

```
DELETE t1 FROM `User_attendance` as f
        INNER JOIN
    `User_attendance` as s 
WHERE
    f.id < s.id AND f.time = s.time AND f.user_attendance_user_id = s.user_attendance_user_id;
```

This will remove the duplicate entries from your table. You might want to make sure you only insert a new row if it is unique, so do a check in your code (and make the column combination of user id and time unique (i.e. a UNIQUE index) in the database)

Comment: No problem. Have a nice day.

Comment: i gat this error SQL query:


DELETE  FROM User_attendance f
        INNER JOIN
    User_attendance s 
WHERE
    f.id < s.id AND f.time = s.time AND f.user_attendance_user_id = s.user_attendance_user_id
MySQL said: 

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'f
        INNER JOIN
    User_attendance s 
WHERE
    f.id < s.id AND f.time' at line 1

Comment: @AwarPulldozer Didn't see your comment until now, but it might be that MariaDB doesn't like the renaming of tables like User_attendance as f. You could try adding the word "as" between User_attendance and f and User_attendance and s.

f and s are nothing more than names so you can distinguish the tables from the main query and the join query. You can choose any name, but I chose f for first and s for second.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

```
User::with('getAttendance')->distinct()->get();
```